# io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Entry occupying heap resulting in OOM

Tags: jms, netty, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

We are connecting to JBoss EAP 7.1.0 GA using JMS in our application. Over a period of 5-10 days we see that our Old Gen eventually runs out of heap due to failed clean up of `io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcherEntry*` which keeps on retaining heap

[image]

I noticed that JBoss client jar is using the bundled Netty library v4.1.9. Below are the Netty version properties:

```
netty-buffer.version=4.1.9.Final-redhat-1
netty-buffer.buildDate=2017-05-19 04\:27\:45 -0400
netty-buffer.commitDate=2017-05-19 10\:08\:15 +0200
netty-buffer.shortCommitHash=e75b1f8
netty-buffer.longCommitHash=e75b1f856d38a057ab0886166a1b2f9578c64c25
netty-buffer.repoStatus=dirty
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 19 May 2017 04:28:16 -0400
```

I found a reference on [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3462621), but I could not access it. I wanted to see if anyone else has seen this problem and has a better way to control this behavior to avoid OOM Error?

Comment: We are connecting to a Jboss 7.1.0 GA EAP

Comment: Are you making sure to close all your JMS sessions, connections, etc. properly? You may be leaking connections resulting in this OOME.